# Class with data member that can be one of two types

Tags: c++, class, templates, variant, any

Probably best explained with some code:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(const std::string& d1, const std::string& d2, const std::vector<AorB>& d3) : data1(d1), data2(d2), data3(d3) {}

    std::string getData1();
    std::string getData2();
    std::vector<AorB> getData3();

  private:
    std::string data1;
    std::string data2;
    std::vector<AorB> data3;
}

int main() {
  MyClass myClassA("d1", "d2", std::vector<A>());
  MyClass myClassB("d1", "d2", std::vector<B>());

  A myA = myClassA.getData3();
  B myB = myClassB.getData3();
}
```

This workflow "almost" works when using boost variants or boost any, but the thing I'm trying to avoid is the call to boost::get on the result of getData3 to get the actual type. In other words, I don't want the consumer of MyClass to have to know whether A or B is stored in data3. I just want them to be able to call getData3() which is whatever type it was passed upon creation.

I think it's possible through templates with template specialization/recursive inheritence, but I can't quite figure out how to get that working. Maybe it will look something like this?

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    template <typename AorB>
    MyClass(const std::string& d1, const std::string& d2, const std::vector<AorB>& d3) : data1(d1), data2(d2), data3(d3) {}

    std::string getData1();
    std::string getData2();

    template <typename AorB>
    std::vector<AorB> getData3();

  private:
    std::string data1;
    std::string data2;

    template <typename AorB>
    std::vector<AorB> data3;
  }

  int main() {
    MyClass myClassA<A>("d1", "d2", std::vector<A>());
    MyClass myClassB<B>("d1", "d2", std::vector<B>());

    A myA = myClassA.getData3();
    B myB = myClassB.getData3();
  }
```

However this won't work because we can't have non-static template class members.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate `std::vector<std::variant<A, B>>` or `std::variant<std::vector<A>, std::vector<B>>`?

Comment: do `A` and `B` inherit from a common base? If not I dont really understand "I don't want the consumer of MyClass to have to know whether A or B is stored in data3" because once they call `getData3` the user does know what type it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you are attempting, you would need to apply the template to `MyClass` as a whole, eg:

```cpp
template <typename AorB>
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass(const std::string& d1, const std::string& d2, const std::vector<AorB>& d3) : data1(d1), data2(d2), data3(d3) {}

    std::string getData1();
    std::string getData2();
    std::vector<AorB> getData3();

  private:
    std::string data1;
    std::string data2;
    std::vector<AorB> data3;
};

int main() {
  MyClass<A> myClassA("d1", "d2", std::vector<A>());
  MyClass<B> myClassB("d1", "d2", std::vector<B>());

  A myA = myClassA.getData3();
  B myB = myClassB.getData3();
}
```

Comment: Oof, that was a trivial fix, feel kinda dumb now. Yeah this does exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use union here to set the datatype whatever you want at the time of creation and that what you got at the time of retrieval.
Union allocates a common memory location for all its members. The memory occupied by a union will be large enough to hold the largest member of the union.

```
union AorB
   {
         A;
         B;
   };
```

Then use in above program

Comment: using a `union` will not allow to return either `A` or `B` from `getData3` unless you suggest to return the union, which leaves it to the caller to know which is the active member

Comment: In which case, there is no benefit to using a `union` over using a `variant` instead